# Using ggvis to show longitudinal data, where a slider controls the year

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I'm trying to use a slider to control year in a longitudinal spatial data set, essentially a set of scatter plots. I can't figure out how to assign the slider to this variable - can you do this in ggvis?

A simplified data set:

```
data <- data.frame(year=rep(2000:2002, each=23), 
                   x=rnorm(23*3,10), y=rnorm(23*3,10),
                   count=c(rnorm(23,2), rnorm(23,4), rnorm(23,6)))
```

What I've tried:

```
### This is what is looks like in ggplot2, I'm aiming to be able to toggle 
### between these panels
ggplot(data, aes(x, y, size=count)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(~year)

### Here is where I'm at with ggvis
data %>% 
   ggvis(~x, ~y, size=~count) %>% 
   layer_points() 
# I'm not sure how to assign a variable (year) to a slider, I've been trying 
# within the layer_points() function

### I also tried using the props() function, but I don't fully understand 
### how to use it.
data %>% 
    ggvis(~x, ~y, size=~count) %>% 
    layer_points() %>% 
    props(prop("fill", input_slider(min(data$year), max(data$year)))) #error message
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can simplify creation of your sample data set: `df = data.frame(year=rep(2000:2002, each=23), x=rnorm(23*3,10), y=rnorm(23*3,10), count=c(rnorm(23,2),rnorm(23,4),rnorm(23,6)))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to use the slider to `filter` the data points (i.e. only show those points from the year selected on the slider), or to show the years in different colors according to the slider's value.

#### Case 1 (only display the points from a specific year)

```
data %>% 
  ggvis(~x, ~y, size=~count) %>% 
  layer_points(opacity=input_slider(min(data$year), max(data$year), step=1, 
                                 map=function(x) ifelse(data$year == x, 1, 0)))
```

#### Case 2 (highlight the selected years)

```
data %>% 
  ggvis(~x, ~y, size=~count) %>% 
  layer_points(fill=input_slider(min(data$year), max(data$year), step=1, 
                                 map=function(x) factor(x == data$year)))
```

---

## EDIT2: How to simply wrap a `left_right()` function.

In the first edit I presented a solution that is not properly considered as *wrapping*. 
I was interested in creating a wrapper of the reactive object returned by `left_right()`, avoiding modifying `create_keyboard_event` all together.

After reading the source code of `ggvis` more thoroughly and more on S4 objects in R, 
I realized that yes, you can simply wrap a reactive object, as long as you preserve the `broker` class and its `broker` attribute appropriately.

This allows us to write more elegant code, like:

```
year_lr <- left_right(1997, 2002, value=2000, step=1)
year_wrapper <- reactive({
  as.numeric(year_lr() == data$year) 
})

class(year_wrapper) <- c("broker", class(year_wrapper))
attr(year_wrapper, "broker") <- attr(year_lr, "broker")

data %>% 
  ggvis(~x, ~y, size=~count) %>% 
  layer_points(opacity:=year_wrapper)
```

## EDIT:  How to create your own (modified) `left_right()` function

user3389288 asked me a good question, that since you don't have a `map` argument for `left_right()` function, how can you actually bind keyboard event to generate custom parameters. For example, in the context of this question, how can we tailor `left_right()` as a year filter?

If you dig into the source code of `ggvis`, you can see that `left_right()` is simply a thin wrapper function calling `create_keyboard_event`.

Hence we can create our own version of `left_right()`, or even `h_j_k_l()` say if you are fanatic about Vi. 
But, here is a big but, if you dig one layer further to look at the implementation of `create_keyboard_event`, you will find that it is not quite suitable for our task.

This is because in order to show some of the dots, while hide others, we have to let `left_right` return a `vector` (that equals to the number of rows in `data`). 
However, both `left_right` and `create_keyboard_event` are created with the assumption that the returned value (which is also the current state of the `value` modified by Left/Right key presses) is a *scalar*.

In order to separate the return value (vector) from the cached current state (scalar, i.e. the *year*), we have to create a slightly modified version of `left_right()` and `create_keyboard_event`.

Below is the source code that would work.

```
data <- data.frame(year=rep(1997:2002, each=12), 
                   x=rnorm(24*3,10), y=rnorm(24*3,10),
                   count=c(rnorm(24,2), rnorm(24,4), rnorm(24,6)))

create_keyboard_event2 <- function(map, default.x = NULL, default.res = NULL) {
  # A different version of ggvis::create_keyboard_event function:
  # the major different is that the map function returns a list,
  # list$x is the current value and list$res the result (returned to a ggvis prop).

  # this seperation allows us to return a vector of different
  # values instead of a single scalar variable.

  if (!is.function(map)) stop("map must be a function")

  vals <- shiny::reactiveValues()
  vals$x <- default.x
  vals$res <- default.res

  # A reactive to wrap the reactive value
  res <- reactive({
    vals$res
  })

  # This function is run at render time.
  connect <- function(session, plot_id) {
    key_press_id  <- paste0(plot_id, "_key_press")

    shiny::observe({
      key_press <- session$input[[key_press_id]]

      if (!is.null(key_press)) {
        # Get the current value of the reactive, without taking a dependency
        current_value <- shiny::isolate(vals$x)

        updated <- map(key_press, current_value)

        vals$x <- updated$x
        vals$res <- updated$res
      }

    })
  }
  ggvis:::connector_label(connect) <- "key_press"

  spec <- list(type = "keyboard")
  ggvis:::create_broker(res, connect = connect, spec = spec)
}

# a modified version of left_right. this closure encapsulates the
# data "year", allowing us to perform comparison of the current state of
# left_right (numeric year number) to the year vector.

left_right_year <- function(min, max, value = (min + max) / 2,
                       step = (max - min) / 40, year) {

  # Given the key_press object and current value, return the next value
  map <- function(key_press, current_value) {
    key <- key_press$value

    print(current_value)

    if (key == "left") {
      new_value <- pmax(min, current_value - step)

    } else if (key == "right") {
      new_value <- pmin(max, current_value + step)

    } else {
      new_value = current_value
    }

    list(x=new_value, res=as.numeric(year == new_value))

  }

  create_keyboard_event2(map, value, as.numeric(value==year))
}

# now with an additional argument, the data$year
alpha_by_year <- left_right_year(1997, 2002, value=2000, step=1, data$year)

data %>% 
  ggvis(~x, ~y, size=~count) %>% 
  layer_points(opacity:=alpha_by_year) # if you let left_right_year return
  # a factor vector, you can use fill:=... as well
```

You can compare `left_right_year` and `create_keyboard_event2` with their vanilla version counterparts.

For example, the original `create_keyboard_event` is:

```
create_keyboard_event <- function(map, default = NULL) {
  if (!is.function(map)) stop("map must be a function")

  vals <- shiny::reactiveValues()
  vals$x <- default

  # A reactive to wrap the reactive value
  res <- reactive({
    vals$x
  })

  # This function is run at render time.
  connect <- function(session, plot_id) {
    key_press_id  <- paste0(plot_id, "_key_press")

    shiny::observe({
      key_press <- session$input[[key_press_id]]

      if (!is.null(key_press)) {
        # Get the current value of the reactive, without taking a dependency
        current_value <- shiny::isolate(vals$x)

        vals$x <- map(key_press, current_value)
      }

    })
  }
  connector_label(connect) <- "key_press"

  spec <- list(type = "keyboard")
  create_broker(res, connect = connect, spec = spec)
}
```

You can see that our modified version will not only cache the current state `vals$x`, but also the return vector `vals$res`.

The variable `vals` is a **reactive value**. The concept is borrowed from Shiny. You can check out [this document](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html) about a high-level overview of reactive values and reactivity in general.

### <strike>A question yet to be answered</strike>

Since `vals$x` is itself a reactive value. Intuitively, if

```
x <- left_right(1, 100, value=20, step=10)
```

then

```
y <- reactive(x() * 2)
```

should allow us to implement a quick `map` function.

However it doesn't work as expected. I am yet to figure out why exactly. If you know the answer, please kindly let me know!

**UPDATED: c.f. EDIT2**

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your `ggplot2` code. If you want the results to look more like `facet_wrap`, probably you'd like the first solution. 

You can also change the `map` function to view the points cumulatively by changing `==` to `>`.

Comment: Great, thank you! Since `left_right()` doesn't have a map argument, do you know if it is possible to still use that function instead of a slider? Just curious!

Comment: The answer is yes you can, but unfortunately it is not trivial. I can update my answer to give you a more detailed explanation.

Comment: This is awesome - thank you for the in depth answer!!

Comment: Hey user3389288, I've edited my answer again after figuring out how to write a simple wrapper for `left_right()` instead of forking the underlying functions of `ggvis`. You might want to use to the new approach since it's much easier, and less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are great. Definitively worth study. This is what I came up with for the original question for a quick fix.

Global.R:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(ggvis)

        data<-data.frame(year=rep(2000:2002, each=23), x=rnorm(23*3,10), y=rnorm(23*3,10),
                        count=c(rnorm(23,2),rnorm(23,4),rnorm(23,6)))
```

ui.R:

```
     shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
         h3("Ploting Diferent Years Using a Slider",align="center"),
         br(),
         fluidRow(column(4,ggvisOutput("yearPlot"),offset=3)),
         fluidRow(column(3,sliderInput("YearSelect", "Year:     ",min=2000,max=2002,step=1,value=2000),offset=5))
))
```

Server.R:

```
    shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

    plotdata <- reactive({
        chosendat <- data[data$year==input$YearSelect, ]
        names(chosendat) <- c("year","xvar","yvar","count")
        return(chosendat)
      })

    vis1% ggvis(~xvar, ~yvar, size=~count) %>% layer_points() 

    })

    vis1 %>% bind_shiny("yearPlot")

    })
```

Comment: Using Shiny is definitely another viable option. However I am never fond of the slider in both Shiny and ggvis. It doesn't support clicking, but only dragging. And there is no debouncing while you drag: you flood the Shiny server with a lot of change events, especially if you have set a very fine `step` parameter.